# Bigquery / Standard SQL - Dummifying arrays

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I am trying to create dummy columns from arrays.

My original dataset looks something like the following

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      UserID         |     Categories   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |   1 44 56 423    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |    44 54 624     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

What I am trying to achieve is a table that dummifies all the categories (e.g. creating a new column of Categories_1, Categories_44, Categories_56 etc), where array length is not fixed.

The output should look something like this - with all possible columns, depending on what is present in the categories column

```
|-----------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|  UserID   |   Categories_1  |  Categories_44  |  Categories_54  |
|-----------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     1     |        1        |        1        |        0        |
|-----------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|     2     |        0        |        1        |        1        |
|-----------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

From the initial table - I've managed to split the categories down with the SPLIT function

```
 SELECT SPLIT(Categories, " ") FROM `dataset.table`
```

It's given me an array, and i'm not too sure how to proceed from here.

Hard coding this with a CASE WHEN would be nearly impossible this because the number of users extend up to tens of thousands, and categories in hundreds

Comment: still not clear what is expected output. could you provide more detailed example / logic?

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope this makes it easier to understand :)

Comment: Very commonly asked question - this is not doable!!! But there are tons of workarounds depends on particular usecase. Share your use case and why you think you need what you asked - so we will be able to help. At the same time as I mentioned this is very frequently asked question and I think I answered such at least few times - search on SO. Keywords would be pivot transpose etc.